# Rails: Ruby debugger shows old code unless I stop the server and start it again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, refresh, ruby-debug

Using ruby-debug, when I issue a `list` command, it shows old code. So if I update the code surrounding (especially before) the `debugger` command in the model it still shows the old code.

The only way I have found to 'refresh' this code is by stopping the server and running it again.

Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just do a `reload`? You can also [set a flag for auto-reloading](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rdebug/) but never tried it myself (I tend to use Netbeans now)

Comment: Using reload didn't work for me but using set autoreload worked great. Thanks.