# Why does the Rails Debugger not default to Autoreloading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-debug

This drove me nuts for the longest time and I thought my rails s was not reloading my code when in fact the debugger was not reloading it.

Then I found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449705/rails-ruby-debugger-shows-old-code-unless-i-stop-the-server-and-start-it-again) post that auto-reloading is not default. WHY NOT???

If you are debugging code, and you see an error, you are clearly trying to change it. And when you change it and the debugger keeps your old buggy code, what's the point?

I would like to set autoreloading to default but right now you have to do this:

rdebug reads its configuration file at startup. 
create a file ~/.rdebugrc with this content:

```
set autoreload
```

or an explanation of how I am using the debugger incorrectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your question is. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: His question is his answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

[This Pivotal Labs article](http://pivotallabs.com/ruby-debug-in-30-seconds-we-don-t-need-no-stinkin-gui/]) should give the answer.

**Caveat:** This worked on my Ubuntu environment, but in my current setup (Mac OS X) I can't get changes in controllers auto reloaded even with this. Could you let me know your setup and if it works for you?

Comment: Yes the solution I initially outlined at the top worked for me. Really sorry for the delayed response!